# iphone 6 is broken and my screen won't work

Tags: ios

My iPhone 6 is broken and the screen won't work it just comes up with green and red and pink lines down and I can't see. I want to be able to back up all my photos. But i have a password so when i plug it onto my laptop is says I can't because my iPhone is locked.

Comment: Thats because the screen is broken. get the screen replaced at either a third party, or by apple.

Put the phone into recovery mode, and then use  a data recovery application for iPhones. then you will be able to recover all the data, and get your phone fixed. but seriously, get into the habit of regular backups of your mobile, for this reason. or just take better care!

Comment: Do you have an iCloud backup? You might be able to recover your photos from iCloud